# A design of functors in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, functor

I have defined 2 modules `Zone` and `Zones`, `Zones` is a list of `Zone`, of cause functions of `Zones` need to call functions of `Zone`:

```
module Zone = struct
 type t = 
 { ...
   prop: bool }
 ...
end

modules Zones = struct
  type t =
  | ZSbot
  | ZS of Zone.t list
  | ZStop
  ...
end
```

A principle file `all.ml` uses `Zones` and `Mis` modules,  `mis.ml` contains functions which work on both `Zone.t` and `Zones.t`, for instance `val Mis.make : Zone.t -> Zones.t`.

```
open Zones
open Mis
type t = { zs: Zones.t }
...
Mis.make z
```

Now, I would like to have more options for the `prop` of `Zone`. So I define an interface `PROPERTY` and 2 modules `Type` and `Formula` matching it, so that I can make functors for `Zone` and others where `... prop: Property.t ...`. Now I can imagine several possibilities for the new `all.ml`:

```
(* 1 *)
open Zones
module ZonesType = ZonesFun(Type)
module ZonesFormula = ZonesFun(Formula)
type t = { zstype: ZonesType.t; zsformula: ZonesFormula }

(* 3 *)
open Zones
module ZonesType = ZonesFun(ZoneFun(Type))
module ZonesFormula = ZonesFun(ZoneFun(Formula))
type t = { zstype: ZonesType.t; zsformula: ZonesFormula }

(* 4 *)
open Zones
module ZoneType = ZoneFun(Type)
module ZoneFormula = ZoneFun(Formula)
module ZonesType = ZonesFun(ZoneType)
module ZonesFormula = ZonesFun(ZoneFormula)
type t = { zstype: ZonesType.t; zsformula: ZonesFormula }
```

Although the signatures of `ZonesFun` and `ZoneFun` are different among the 3 options, this implementation can make sure `ZoneXXX.t` and `ZonesXXX.t` are coherent. Now one big problem is how to change `Mis`:

1) If I make a functor `MisFun: PROPERTY -> MIS`, and build the `ZoneXXX` and `ZonesXXX` inside. It cannot know `MisXXX.Zone.t` is same as `Zone.t` of `all.ml`, or `MisXXX.Zones.t` is same as `Zones.t` of `all.ml`.

2) If I make a functor `MisFun: Zone -> Zones -> MIS`, it cannot know `MisXXX.Zone.t` and `MisXXX.Zones.t` are coherent.

Does anyone know how to solve both 1) and 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Option (1), do you apply `ZoneFun` inside `ZonesFun`?

Assuming that, I think the choice is between (1) and (3)/(4) (which seem to be the same). Which one to pick depends on whether you need to be able to access the created `Zone` modules outside `ZoneFun` (you need (4)) or not ((1) works fine).

**Update in reply to update:**

If I understand your question correctly, then it seems to me that `Mis` has to become a functor as well. Moreover, its signature can specify types like

```
val make: ZoneFun(X).t -> ZonesFun(X).t
```

where `X` is the functor parameter.

(Btw, I still see no difference between (3) and (4), except that you name the auxiliary modules.)

**Update 2:**

My guess is that you are running into an old and unfortunate bug in OCaml's module type checker (see [this discussion on the caml list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/fa.caml/dreyer/fa.caml/nhwBGaOhRRU/pXTGt8Ex7RoJ)). The following *ought to* work, but doesn't:

```
module type PROP = sig type t end
module type ZONE = sig type t end
module MakeZone (P : PROP) = struct type t = {p : P.t} end
module MakeZones (Z : ZONE) = struct type t = ZS of Z.t list end

module MakeMisc (P : PROP) :
sig
  val make : MakeZone(P).t -> MakeZones(MakeZone(P)).t
end =
struct
  module Zone = MakeZone(P)
  module Zones = MakeZones(Zone)
  let make z = Zones.ZS [z]
end

module Type = struct type t = T end
module Formula = struct type t = F end
module ZoneType = MakeZone(Type)
module ZoneFormula = MakeZone(Formula)
module ZonesType = MakeZones(ZoneType)
module ZonesFormula = MakeZones(ZoneFormula)
module MiscType = MakeMisc(Type)
module MiscFormula = MakeMisc(Formula)
let zst = MiscType.make {ZoneType.p = Type.T}
let zsf = MiscFormula.make {ZoneFormula.p = Formula.F}
```

You can force to make it work by putting in type annotations in `MakeMisc` as follows:

```
module MakeMisc (P : PROP) :
sig
  val make : MakeZone(P).t -> MakeZones(MakeZone(P)).t
end =
struct
  module Zone : sig type t = MakeZone(P).t end = MakeZone(P)
  module Zones :
    sig type t = MakeZones(MakeZone(P)).t = ZS of MakeZone(P).t list end =
    MakeZones(MakeZone(P))
  let make z = Zones.ZS [z]
end
```

But obviously, that's not very pleasant.

However, the common way to express sharing in ML, anyway, is by *fibration*, where you name the types or modules you want to share with abstractly in the signatures and refine them accordingly. Then you can turn `Zone` and `Zones` into additional parameters of the `Misc` functor:

```
module type PROP = sig type t end
module type ZONE = sig type prop type t = {p : prop} end
module type ZONES = sig type zone type t = ZS of zone list end
module MakeZone (P : PROP) = struct type prop = P.t type t = {p : prop} end
module MakeZones (Z : ZONE) = struct type zone = Z.t type t = ZS of zone list end

module MakeMisc
  (P : PROP) (Z : ZONE with type prop = P.t) (Zs : ZONES with type zone = Z.t) :
sig
  val make : Z.t -> Zs.t
end =
struct
  let make z = Zs.ZS [z]
end

module Type = struct type t = T end
module Formula = struct type t = F end
module ZoneType = MakeZone(Type)
module ZoneFormula = MakeZone(Formula)
module ZonesType = MakeZones(ZoneType)
module ZonesFormula = MakeZones(ZoneFormula)
module MiscType = MakeMisc(Type)(ZoneType)(ZonesType)
module MiscFormula = MakeMisc(Formula)(ZoneFormula)(ZonesFormula)
let zst = MiscType.make {ZoneType.p = Type.T}
let zsf = MiscFormula.make {ZoneFormula.p = Formula.F}
```

Comment: In Option (1), `ZoneFun` is applied inside `ZonesFun`.